# How to create unique indexes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I create table with migration in laravel 5.6.

I need create a unique indexes with migration.

My code is:

```
$table->index([
            'system',
            'code',
            'city',
            'seat',
            'type'
        ], 'PrimaryPayment');
```

But after run `migrate` . in `phpmyadmin -> table -> table_name -> indexes` show `unique: No`

How to create unique indexes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-indexes) method on migration:

```
$table->string('email')->unique();
```

Or like this for `compound unique` index:

```
$table->unique([
        'system',
        'code',
        'city',
        'seat',
        'type'
    ], 'PrimaryPayment');
```

Comment: Should I create a migration file manually for this purpose? Or can I modify the Model and then run Artisan command for automatics migration generation?

Comment: i would go with new migration file rather than modifying existing classes/files