# Add unique index in Laravel Migration

Tags: sql-server, laravel-migrations

How to set a unique index for SQL Server in a Laravel migration file?

I have tried the following but no luck for SQL Server 2017:

```php
   /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('sheet',50)->index('sheet')->unique()->nullable()->comment('...');
        });
    }
```

If I simply try with unique(), it doesn't work either

```php
   /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unique('sheet',50)->nullable()->comment('...');
        });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `->index('sheet')->unique()` is ambiguous. Just unique() must work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127291/how-to-create-unique-indexes-in-laravel